# Nativescript-Vue app icon recommended resolutions and formats

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I'm new to nativescript, I want to change my app icon, after looking for some info I came up with the following command:

```
tns resources generate splashes <path to image> [--background <color>]
```

for easily creating and adding images/icons to the resources folders. However there's no info about the recommended size, resolutions and type of file I have to provide.

Can I just provide an svg image and be done with it, afaik svg doesn't decrease it's quality.

Comment: Generally you would use the same app icon on the splash screen at center. If you are doing so, I guess 1024 x 1024 PNG file should do the job.

Comment: can I use a png with a transparent background?

Comment: I don't think apple allows transparency in your icon, it may affect when you hit app store. Also the default background color for launch screen will be white.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sidekick](https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-sidekick) to generate your icons as described [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/configure-app/assets-management)